# Dynamically showing templates in Meteor without re-rendering/re-creating template

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

Long time user of SO but first time poster.

I have a Meteor web application where a user is presented with a page with a single input. Once they action it, the following section appears below. This process repeats.

**Journey.html**

```
<head>
  <title>Page Journey</title>    

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function showValue(newValue)
    {
        document.getElementById("range").innerHTML=newValue;
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
  {{> Page0}}

  {{> Page1}}

  {{> Page2}}

  {{> Page3}}
</body>

<template name="Page0">
  <h1>This is Page 0!</h1>  
  <p>Welcome to Journey App.</p>
  <input type="range" min="1" max="10" value="1" step="1" onchange="showValue(this.value)" />
    <span id="range">1</span>
</template>

<template name="Page1">
    {{#if showpage1}}
  <h1>This is Page 1!</h1>  
  <p>{{page1copy}}</p>
  <input type="button" value="Show Page 2" />
  {{/if}}
</template>

<template name="Page2">
    {{#if showpage2}}
  <h1>This is Page 2!</h1>
  <p>{{page2copy}}</p>
  <input type="button" value="Show Page 3" />
  {{/if}}
</template>

<template name="Page3">
    {{#if showpage3}}
  <h1>This is Page 3!</h1>
  <p>{{page3copy}}</p>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

**Journey.js**

```
//On initialization, set position to 0.
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    Session.set("position",0);
  });
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Template.Page0.events({
    'click input': function () {
      var value = getValue();
      if (value>5)         {        Session.set("position",1);        }
      else                 {        Session.set("position",0);        }
    }
  });

    Template.Page1.events({
    'click input': function () {      
      //Increment position
      Session.set("position",2);
    }
  });

    Template.Page2.events({
    'click input': function () {      
      //Increment position
      Session.set("position",3);
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.Page1.showpage1 = function () {
    return Session.get("position") > 0;
  }

  Template.Page2.showpage2 = function () {
    return Session.get("position") > 1;
  }

  Template.Page3.showpage3 = function () {
    return Session.get("position") > 2;
  }
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.Page1.rendered = function(){
    console.log ('Page 1 rendered');
  };

  Template.Page2.rendered = function(){
    console.log ('Page 2 rendered');
  };

  Template.Page3.rendered = function(){
    console.log ('Page 3 rendered');
  };
}

function getValue()
{
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById("range").innerHTML);
  return value;
}
```

Am I going about this all wrong?

I want to fire off a function (google analytics tracking code, for example) every time that a new page loads. The `.rendered()` function gets fired when the page loads up the first time around, so this isn't ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to listen to the change of your session variable like this:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Deps.autorun(function(){
    var position=Session.get("position");
    console.log("POSITION HAS CHANGED TO "+position);
  });
}
```

On another level, I think you could make your life easier by moving your conditions in the same template and using a helper. Like this:

```
<body>
  {{>pages}}
</body>

<template name="pages">
  {{> Page0}}
  {{#if showpage 1}}
    {{> Page1}}
  {{/if}}
  {{#if showpage 2}}
    {{> Page2}}
  {{/if}}
  {{#if showpage 3}}
    {{> Page3}}
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

And in your .js file:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.pages.showpage = function (p) {
    return (Session.get("position")>=p);
  };
}
```

It has the additionnal effect that your "rendered" callbacks will only be called if the template is actually on screen.
Though, when the 3 is rendered, 1 and 2 will also be called because the session variable (`position`) will trigger the whole `pages` template to refresh.

So the log output will look like this

```
POSITION HAS CHANGED TO 0
POSITION HAS CHANGED TO 1
Page 1 rendered
POSITION HAS CHANGED TO 2
Page 1 rendered
Page 2 rendered
POSITION HAS CHANGED TO 3
Page 1 rendered
Page 2 rendered
Page 3 rendered
```

If you want your callback to be fired once when the template appears on the page, but not when it is refreshed, you can use `Template.pageX.created` instead of `Template.pageX.rendered`.

```
POSITION HAS CHANGED TO 0 
POSITION HAS CHANGED TO 1 
Page 1 created 
Page 1 rendered 
POSITION HAS CHANGED TO 2 
Page 2 created 
Page 1 rendered 
Page 2 rendered 
POSITION HAS CHANGED TO 3 
Page 3 created 
Page 1 rendered 
Page 2 rendered 
Page 3 rendered
```

Because all your templates depends on the same session variable, everytime it changes, all your templates are re-rendered.

If you want to avoid that, The only solution I think of is to use different session variables for each subpage. Be prepared, it's gonna get a bit ugly, but I really don't know other ways :)

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  function setPosition(a){
    // only touch the following pages
    for(var i=3; i>a; --i)
      Session.set("position-"+i,false);  
    Session.set("position-"+a,true);
  }

  Meteor.startup(function () {
    setPosition(0);
  });

  Template.Page0.events({
    'click input': function () {
      var value = getValue();
      if (value>5)         {        setPosition(1);        }
      else                 {        setPosition(0);        }
    }
  });

    Template.Page1.events({
    'click input': function () {      
      //Increment position
      setPosition(2);
    }
  });

    Template.Page2.events({
    'click input': function () {      
      //Increment position
      setPosition(3);
    }
  });

  Template.pages.showpage = function (p) {
    return (Session.get("position-"+p));
  };
}
```

If you do just this, it will not work yet, because the `pages` template will now depends on the three session variables, so it will be entirely re-rendered upon modification of any of those variables.

You need to split your templates so that they depends on only one session variable each. But we want to be able to keep the helper that we made before, right ?

So we can use the `{{#isolate}}` helper that will virtually separate some parts of our template.

```
  {{#isolate}}
    {{> Page0}}
  {{/isolate}}

  {{#isolate}}
    {{#if showpage 1}}
      {{> Page1}}
    {{/if}}
  {{/isolate}}

  {{#isolate}}
    {{#if showpage 2}}
      {{> Page2}}
    {{/if}}
  {{/isolate}}

  {{#isolate}}
    {{#if showpage 3}}
      {{> Page3}}
    {{/if}}
  {{/isolate}}
```

Now the log is like this:

```
Page 1 created 
Page 1 rendered 
Page 2 created 
Page 2 rendered 
Page 3 created 
Page 3 rendered
```

Comment: That's really helpful, thanks! If i replaced Template.rendered() with Template.created() then it would only fire once per template?

Comment: yes, each time the template is added to the page. This means that if the `position` gets back to zero for some reason, and then increase again, the callbacks will be fired because the template have been removed and are added again.

But if something change inside of one of your subpages, you won't get notified

Comment: Ok. This is a separate question now, but how could I get page 1 and 2 NOT to re-render when position is incremented to 3? I have some custom plug-ins being initialised in each page that I don't want to reset.

Comment: Here is my take on this, I would really like to see better solutions

Comment: Interestingly enough, Meteor 0.8.0 update (Blaze) solves this issue of Template.rendered() firing more than once.
As a result #isolate and #constant have been deprecated from this update.